# QNX posix signal is lost when two same signals come very closely

Tags: signals, posix, real-time, interrupt-handling, qnx

I have implemented periodic task class with posix interval timers just like on: 
http://quirk.ch/2009/07/how-to-use-posix-timer-within-c-classes

In the main thread, i am instantiating 2 of them with same itimerspec value and interval (say: 1 sec both) and than call the start functions of 2 tasks (without any other code in between the start functions).

When i try this in non-realtime linux, it works as expected. Both of tasks are executed like this:

TASK1

TASK2

(interval waiting time spent here)

TASK1

TASK2

(interval waiting time spent here)
.
.

This behaviour in non RT linux is not surprising to me, since (probably by statistics / luck), no signal is created, while the other signal is handled.

However when i run this code in real time QNX, All i get is

TASK2

TASK2

.
.

I know that printf is not safe within signal handler, however i also debugged and the TASK1 is never executed. Also, the result does not change eiter with the global flag method.

**The interesting part is when i put at least 2 nanoseconds of sleep between each task's start function, then both TASK1 and TASK2 is printed.**

I know that posix signals may coalesced (but i suppose this situtation may only occur, if signals are not queued). And, as far as i know, posix standart signal are not queued, but realtime signals are. So, I also repeeted these experiments with SIGRTMIN signal, result is the same.

Moreover on this site:
http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.2/neutrino/sys_arch/kernel.html

QNX authors claim that:

> Since the signals are always blocked, the program cannot be
>   interrupted or killed if the special signal is delivered outside of
>   the sigwaitinfo() function. Since signal queuing is always enabled,
>   signals won't be lost -- they'll be queued for the next sigwaitinfo()
>   call.

My guess is that second task signal is created when first task's signal is handled. Moreover either of the 2 below:

- The 2nd time is all of the execution time of the handler and new signal is never blocked, when the first signal is handled (which is strange) and that is why first task is never completed, but always second task is completed.
- **Or there is some very small time (2ns), in between creation of signal and the blocking of the same signal. And since i am not
  putting any time taking code in between two task's start calls, that
  would take more than 2ns, then that is where i hit with the second
  tasks genereated signal. Therefore first task signal is lost before
  handled (because signal is not blocked at that time).**

*I favor my second guess. But then how can a signal be guarenteed that it won't be lost- as QNX site claims?*

**Note: the two tasks use the same signal.**

Thank you for any help.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ExampleTask.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Start of program.." << std::endl;

    struct itimerspec spec;
    spec.it_interval.tv_sec = 1;
    spec.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
    spec.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
    spec.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;

    /*
    for(int i=0; i<1; i++){
      ExampleTask task(spec,i);
      task.start();
    }
    */
    ExampleTask task1(spec,1);
    ExampleTask task2(spec,2);
    task1.start();
    task2.start();
    while(true){
      std::cout << "main loop.." << std::endl;
      sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

PeriodicTask.cpp

```
#include "PeriodicTask.h"
#include "string.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

PeriodicTask::PeriodicTask(struct itimerspec spec){
  this->spec = spec;
  sigemptyset(&this->signalAction.sa_mask);
  this->signalAction.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
  this->signalAction.sa_sigaction = PeriodicTask::signalHandler;

  memset(&this->signalEvent, 0, sizeof(this->signalEvent));
  this->signalEvent.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
  this->signalEvent.sigev_value.sival_ptr = (void*) this;
  this->signalEvent.sigev_signo = SIGALRM;

  if(timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &this->signalEvent, &this->timerID) != 0) {
    perror("Could not create the timer");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if(sigaction(SIGALRM, &this->signalAction, NULL)) {
    perror("Could not install new signal handler");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
}

PeriodicTask::~PeriodicTask(){
  //TODO deconstructor
}

void PeriodicTask::start(){
  this->initialize();
  if(timer_settime(this->timerID, 0, &this->spec, NULL) == -1) {
    perror("Could not start timer:");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
}

void PeriodicTask::stop(){
    this->finalize();
    // TODO remove signals and timers
}

void PeriodicTask::signalHandler(int sigNumb, siginfo_t *si, void *uc){
  PeriodicTask* task = static_cast<PeriodicTask*> (si->si_value.sival_ptr);
  task->execute();
}
```

ExampleTask.cpp

```
#include "ExampleTask.h"
#include "stdio.h"

double getSystemNanosecond(void){
   struct timespec ts;
   int status = clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
   //long long int total = (ts.tv_sec%100)*1000000000 + (ts.tv_nsec);
   //return (double)(total/1000000000);
   return (double)(ts.tv_sec%100) + (double)((double)ts.tv_nsec/(double)1000000000);
}

#define debug(fmt, ...) printf("%0.9f:: " fmt, getSystemNanosecond(), __VA_ARGS__);

ExampleTask::ExampleTask(struct itimerspec spec, int id) : PeriodicTask(spec){
  this->id = id;
}

ExampleTask::~ExampleTask(){
  //TODO deconstructor
}

void ExampleTask::initialize(){
  //TODO initialize
}

void ExampleTask::finalize(){
  //TODO finalize
}

void ExampleTask::execute(){
  //TODO not safe
  debug("%d\n",this->id);
}
```

PeriodicTask.h

```
#ifndef PERIODICTASK_H
#define PERIODICTASK_H

#include "signal.h"
#include "time.h"


class PeriodicTask {
public:
  PeriodicTask(struct itimerspec spec);
  virtual ~PeriodicTask();
  void start();
  void stop();
private:
  static void signalHandler(int sigNumb, siginfo_t *si, void *uc);
  virtual void initialize()=0;
  virtual void finalize()=0;
  virtual void execute()=0;
  struct itimerspec spec;
  timer_t timerID;
  sigset_t sigBlockSet;
  struct sigevent signalEvent;
  struct sigaction signalAction;

};


#endif
```

ExampleTask.h

```
#ifndef EXAMPLETASK_H
#define EXAMPLETASK_H

#include "PeriodicTask.h"

class ExampleTask : public PeriodicTask {
public:
  ExampleTask(struct itimerspec spec, int id);
  virtual ~ExampleTask();
private:
  void initialize();
  void finalize();
  void execute();
  int id;
};

#endif
```

Comment: Can you please share the code?

Comment: @Shaibal Sorry for my late response.. You can find the code in my edit.